Difference between 韩国 and 韩文？
Hopefully another easy question for everyone. How can I remember which version of “Korean” to use in a sentence? I had a question which asked me to translate “I eat Korean snacks”.
I was told I should’ve used 我吃韩国零食 and not 我吃韩文零食?

This is not a Chinese language question. In English, the phrase I speak Korean is short for I speak the Korean language. The phrase I eat Korean snacks is not short for I eat the Korean language snacks. You need to understand how the English words Korean, Japanese, Chinese, Portuguese, French, etc. work.

韩国 translates in Korea and 韩文 translate into Korean.
When you say 我吃韩国零食, it really an abbreviated version of 我吃韩国的零食。
"韩国的零食" = "snacks made in Korea" (ie Korean snacks). But 韩文 refers specifically to the Korean language.
You should only use 韩文 if it makes sense fitting into the sentence as Korean language/literature. For the term Korean used as "belonging to Korea", 韩国 should always be used.

great answer, just want to add that sometimes you could see either abbreviated to just 韓-- this usually only happens in situations with very clear context, and its recommended not to abbreviate yourself unless familiar with the usually process.

Great answer. Thank you. I figured it would be something along these lines, so it’s good to have that clarification.

Both 韩国 and 韩文 are compound words, the proper use of each can be easily determined by recognizing the differences between the root words - 国(country/state) vs 文(language).
"Korean snack" really stands for "韩国(的)零食" - "snack(s) produced/made in the state of Korea".
